# Node.js IPv6 issue

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, google-cloud-platform, ipv6

Node.js server is deployed on Google Cloud Platform and the server is not listening on ipv6.
When I run my API in a mobile browser(chrome) I am seeing this error: *This site can't provide a secure connection.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*

How to make node.js server run on ipv6?
Following is my code:

```
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(
  '/path/to/privkey.pem',
  'utf8'
);
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(
  '/path/to/cert.pem',
  'utf8'
);
const ca = fs.readFileSync(
  '/path/to/chain.pem',
  'utf8'
);

const options = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  ca: ca
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, '::', () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
  });
```

Comment: On which service are you running this code? Only certain Google Managed services support IPv6. Also, your code is trying to set up SSL on a non-standard port (8080).

Comment: are you using Compute Engine or App Engine?

Comment: I am using Compute Engine. If I create a server with HTTP (port 80) then it is running on IPv6, but I can't use IPv6 with HTTPS.

Comment: just do double check you setup a LoadBalancer to use ipv6 with an instance in GCP? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6

Comment: Yes, we have already configured a load balancer to use with IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try this piece of code. You should be able to check it in 8082's port in localhost: https://localhost:8082/

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8082);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work. Please share another solution if anybody knows something about this issue.

Comment: I am able to use IPv6 by creating a server with HTTP on port 80 but IPv6 is not working with HTTPS.